# Loop through a directory to search for two possible matching files

Tags: python

Ok so I'm writing a module that will take in some command line arguments, one of the arguments: `fundCodes` will be an array of funds: `['PUSFF', 'AGE', 'AIR']`

My module has to search through files in a directory and look for files matching a certain format:

```
def file_match(self, fundCodes):
    # Get a list of the files
    files = set(os.listdir(self.unmappedDir))

    # loop through all the files and search for matching file
    for check_fund in fundCodes:
        # set a file pattern
        file_match = 'unmapped_positions_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=check_fund, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)

        # Yet to be used...
        file_trade_match = 'unmapped_trades_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=check_fund, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)

        # look in the unmappeddir and see if there's a file with that name
        if file_match in files:

            # if there's a match, load unmapped positions as etl
            filename = os.path.join(self.unmappedDir, file_match)
            return self.read_file(filename)
        else:
            Logger.error('No file found with those dates/funds')
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to search through the directory for two different formats.

Examples of the formats would be:

`unmapped_trades_AGE_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv` and
`unmapped_positions_AGE_2018-07-01_2018-07-11.csv`

I'm thinking I just need to assign each match to a variable and in my last iteration check if there's a file equal to either value right? It seems redundant though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Before anything: are you **sure** you want to name your inner variables the same name as your outer function (e.g. `file_match`)?

Comment: No, I would change that. I had it initially as `file_match` when there was only one file to match. I realize I'll have to change this once I check for two files.

Comment: Do you really need to use `listdir`? You can just use `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.unmappedDir, file_match)`

Comment: Your function returns when it finds the first match, and doesn't process the rest of the funds. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Hm... It should do it for every fund.. That's why I wrote in a loop. It should go through every fund in the array, but right, once it returns it exits the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just do two `in` tests. If you need both files to exist you can use `and`:

```
if file_match in files and file_trade_match in files:
    # do something
else:
    # log error
```

If you just want to process either file, you can do:

```
if file_match in files:
    # do something
elif file_trade_match in files:
    # do something else
else:
    # log error
```

Comment: OK, I changed it back to his set.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions for this, e.g.

```
import re
import os

search_pattern = 'unmapped_{}_([\w]+)_([0-9\-]+)_([0-9\-]+).csv'
data_types = ['trades', 'positions']
pattern_dict = {data_type: search_pattern.format(data_type) for data_type in data_types}

def find_matching_files(search_dir, fund_codes):
    if not os.path.isdir(search_dir):
        raise ValueError('search_dir does not specify a directory')
    search_files = os.listdir(search_dir)
    matching_files = {data_type: [] for data_type in pattern_dict}
    for fname in search_files:
        for data_type, pattern in pattern_dict.items():
            m = re.match(pattern, fname)
            if m is not None and m.group(1) in fund_codes:
                matching_files[data_type].append(fname)
    return matching_files

print(find_matching_files('file_location/', ['PUSFF', 'AGE', 'AIR']))
```

where `file_location/` is the directory to search, and a dictionary of the matching files separated into data types is returned